# How can text files be written using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, file

In .NET, a file can be written to the file system using:

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(@"Filename");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
// etc...
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

How would I achieve the same operation in Objective-C and Cocoa? I believe it involves the NSMutableData class, but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: You don't need Cocoa for this. Just Foundation Kit either from Apple or GNUStep is fine. :)

Comment: According to Apple's Cocoa Fundamentals Guide in the "What Is Cocoa?" section, the Foundation framework is considered part of Cocoa. http://bit.ly/elRg6n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiny Mac Tutorials has [a post on this.](http://macateeny.blogspot.com/2008/09/write-to-files-with-this-objective-c.html)

The example code from that post is below:

```
// filetest.m
// Created by macateeny.blogspot.com Sept 2008.
// Copyleft (c) 2008. some rights reserved.
// 
// Compile from the command line with:
// gcc filetest.m -Wall -o filetest -framework Foundation
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// main entry point of our file test tool with the argument counter and vector
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    // allocate a memory pool for our NSString Objects
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // declare NSString Obj pointer and initialise it
    NSString *str = @"Cooking with Objective-C\r\n";

    // declare NSString filename and alloc string value
    NSString *filenameStr = @"./filetest.txt";

    // NSObject which contains all the error information
    NSError *error;

    // write contents and check went ok
    if(![str writeToFile: filenameStr atomically: YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"We have a problem %@\r\n",[error localizedFailureReason]);
    }

    // unleash the allocated pool smithers
    [pool release];

    // The app is terminated
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For future reference, answers that simply point to external resources are generally discouraged, as they're not much use if (for example) the external resource is down/moves/removed.

Comment: @middaparka: Where are they discouraged? Maybe Bryan could include some information about the link but ultimately they are sharing information, what's so bad about that? If you are worried about external resources being down/moved/removed then everyone will have to copy every part of the internet they want to reference.

Comment: @Tony They're bad for the reasons I listed. Incidentally, you might want to read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) amongst others

Comment: @Tony agree, and if a resource is Gone (or often Not Found, which is extremely wrong but web developers don't f**king care) you can often find it back in The Internet Archive. :)

Comment: @middaparka: Fair point. I read the question and top voted answer and there are some valid concerns made. Yes, there should be some more information in an answer than just a link but in this case it points to a clear example the OP can follow to achieve what they are trying to accomplish. As to link rot isn't that applicable to the *entire* content of the internet? What would you have said if Byran had coped the entire article from the link and posted it as his own, I'm sure you would should "plagiarism".

Comment: Since I cited the article and kept the header, I don't think it counts as plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Objective C is a pure superset of standard C .  Most of the usual posix library calls (in stdio, stdlib, etc.) are available and usable, as long as you don't try to use them to escape the app's sandbox (write to system directories, etc.)

So fopen() and fprintf() will also work perfectly well for writing ASCII or UTF8 text and data to files.  You can use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains to find the appropriate directory names, and use various NSString convenience methods to convert NSStrings to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"Wollah";
[str writeToFile:@"/Wollah.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Although using an NSURL is recommended, and I always do that.

Comment: atomically means that the file will first be written to the tmp dir and afterwards copied to it's destination. This prevents file corruption when the writing is aborted or failed.

Comment: @boyfarrell it is not: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:

Comment: Cheeky Time Machine! You just changed that from the deprecated version! [str writeToFile:@"/Wollah.txt" atomically:YES];

Comment: I was just editing it while you were writing the comment. :) I didn't notice your comment while editing. I knew the encoding must always be specified so I took a look into the docs. ^^

Answer (score 0):

See [Apple's development docs - Cocoa concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) especially for this re [Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html) The Apple overview documents of the librairead all the concepts first it will give you a idea of what details you need

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of Cocoa on iOS or MacOS you can do this if you don't want to check for an error,

```
NSString *str = @"Wollah";
[str writeToFile:@"Wollah.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score -1):

`NSString` has a `writeToFile` method.

Comment: writeToFile: is deprecated. Use writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error: instead.